# ASP.Net Core Secure Cookie behind Azure Application Gateway

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, cookies, https

I have an ASP.Net Core 3.1 application that used to be hosted on an Azure WebApp with SSL enabled. Now I need to move the app to a Kubernetes Cluster (managed AKS). For ingress, an Azure Application Gateway is used, which also handles and terminates the SSL connection.
As a result, all traffic is routed from the Application Gateway to the app via HTTP (without SSL) and ASP doesn't set the `Secure` attribute (which is required in Chrome because of `SameSite=None`) on the cookie required for authentication.
Following the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer) regarding hosting ASP behind proxies or load balancers, I already included

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions {
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedHost | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
});
```

Still, the login fails on chrome and I can see in the browser tools that the cookie does not have the secure attribute.
I use the following cookie options:

```cs
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options => {
    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
    options.HttpOnly = HttpOnlyPolicy.Always;
    options.Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
});
```

Comment: So it seems the Application Gateway Ingress Controller (AGIC) simlpy doesn't provide the `X-Forward-Proto` header, contrary to the docs linked above. I manually added a rewrite to the Application Gateway to add the header, but as each AKS-deployment creates new rules, the rewrite must be manually associated to these rules again after each deployment.